# Regex: how can I extract <@U34|firstname name|F>

Tags: java, regex

In this string (example)
I receive this: `<@U34|firstname name|F>`;

so I want to extract all groups information:

```
"U": it's the type of user (U or C)
"34": identifier
"firstname name": user identity
"F": user gender (F or M)
```

So I've created this regex, but it doesn't work properly to extract user gender element:

```
"<@(C|U)(\\d+)\\|(.+?)|(M|F)>"
```

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: You should escape the last  `|`, use [`<@([CU])(\d+)\|(.+?)\|([MF])>`](https://regex101.com/r/feNFT0/1)

Comment: You missed the `\ ` in `|(M|F)`.

Comment: `<@([UC])(\d+)\|([^\|]+)\|([FM])>` https://regex101.com/r/lBdafZ/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to escape a pipe:

```
<@(C|U)(\d+)\|(.+?)\|(M|F)>
```

In Java:

```
"<@(C|U)(\\d+)\\|(.+?)\\|(M|F)>"
```

[Online test](https://regex101.com/r/GdXOmD/2)

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if it solved